# changing drawer icon background using sherlockactionbar and customview for action bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, navigation-drawer

I'm using `sherlock actionBar` and I call `actionBar.setCustomView(customView);`. I also use `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.` And I call `actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#323031")));`
The problem is that my `customView` has its `background color (#585054)`, the tabs has their own color (which is not `#323031.` I don't know where their color came from. it's `#464445`). And the `drawer icon` has a different `color (#323031)`.
if I call `actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#585054")));` then the tabs get this color: `#686165` and the drawer gets `#585054`.
So it looks like the drawer gets whatever I set inside `actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable`. But the tabs change their color in a way I don't understand.
***How do I control the color of the tabs, without changing the color of the drawer icon?***
Or ***how can I change the background color of the drawer icon without changing the color of the tabs..?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solved it:

```
 <style name="Theme.slide_menu" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">#323031</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">#323031</item>
</style>
```